# how to change output before rendering in agile toolkit?

Tags: atk4

Is there any hook to change the output before being rendered?

I want to change the last full output (not changing the views)

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

have a look at "output" method in the AbstractView.

ApiFrontend extends ApiWeb which extends ApiCLI which extends AbstractView

so, you can redefine output() method in your api to do any postprocessing you need. If you need to tailor output for ajax requests, then it's a bit different story, and you have to   play with output method in the page/view that is being reloaded.

hope that helps